# Place image next to text with line break

Tags: html, css

I have a footer which shall consist of three parts, which all shall be on the same line:

- a text which consists of one line break
- an image with the same height as the two line text
- two links

My source looks like this:

```
<div>
<p style="float: left">text text text text text text <br/>text text text text text text</p>
<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/30/116" height="30" width="116"/></p>
</div>

<div style="float: right">
Link1 | Link2
</div>
```

The result roughly looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/25/). How do I change the code to have everything appear one a straight line?

Comment: you probably should add the styling that you are trying to make happen so that we get a decent idea of what you are asking for.

Comment: Break tags really shouldn't be used for spacing...use another paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/26/

```
<div style="float: left">text text text text text text <br/>text text text text text text</div>
<div style="float: left">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/30/116" height="30" width="116"/>
</div>

<div style="float: right">
Link1 | Link2
</div>
```